# How to wrap my whole code in flickity js into a function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, flickity

I cannot find any tutorials on how to modify this flickity js code. I am completely new with vanilla js and I admit that I do not have good knowledge with it. This is my code but the flickity slider is not working anymore when I wrapped the whole code into a function.

```
const slider = () => {
  new Flickity( '.slider', {

    cellAlign: 'left',
    draggable: true,
    contain: true,
    wrapAround: true,
    autoPlay: 2000,
    arrowShape: { 
      x0: 10,
      x1: 60, y1: 50,
      x2: 65, y2: 45,
      x3: 20
    }
  });  
}

export default slider
```

Comment: Are you actually calling the function after declaring it? Like `slider()`

Comment: yes, i am actually calling the function, the whole code shoud be wrapped in const slider = () => {}, and when I did it the slider is no longer working.

Comment: Is anything printed in the console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: hideNavigation is not defined
    at Module../src/js/components/hideNavigation.js (hideNavigation.js:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../src/js/index.js (index.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object.1 (main.js:20186)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, Thanks to @camaulay, I didn't notice the console. One of my js files is not under a function so the compiler won't let me compile my codes.